# automate a SQL query to run every month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-express

I have a simple SQL query that updates some date fields in a record, on a **SQL Express** instance.

I'd like to have it run automatically every month.  What is the best way of accomplishing this in SQL Server 2005 Express using the Management Studio?

Comment: Have a .bat file run on a certain day to do this query, could work.

Comment: Why would you ever use a .bat when you can use a job that is built into SQL Server exactly for this purpose?

Comment: @matt, because you didn't read the question.  sql server express doesn't come with sql server agent.  ie, the thing that lets you schedule tasks in sql server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For SQL Server Express, there are a few possibilities. Unfortunately none of them involve Management Studio:

1. Use a combination of [Windows
   Scheduler, sqlcmd.exe, and .bat
   files](http://www.ehow.com/how_6022495_schedule-sql-server-2005-express.html)
2. Use [SQL Server Service Broker](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/scheduling-jobs-in-sql-server-express)
3. Use a [Codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLAgent.aspx) variation of SQL Agent
4. Use [SQL Scheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx) (free
   download)

Answer (score 0):

Create a job with monthly schedule in Sql Agent and assign a T-Sql task to it with this query.

Comment: I don't seem to see a SQL Agent. Sorry I failed to mention this was Sql Server 2005 Express and I'm using Management Studio Express.  Can I still accomplish this?  Thanks!

Comment: This would be a good option if there was another non-Express SKU of SQL Server running elsewhere.

Comment: down voted because they didn't look up that express doesn't come with sql server agent.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of bat file to connect to your sql express using sqlcmd.exe and then set that bat file in windows scheduler to run it at desired time of interval.