# How to create jobs in SQL Server Express edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-express, sql-job

Could anyone please explain to me how to create jobs in `SQL Server Express` edition?

Comment: If you are referring to SQL Agent jobs, that functionality is not available in Express edition. See the answer to this question for other possibilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788583/automate-a-sql-query-to-run-every-month/3789024#3789024

Comment: Express edition supports SQL Server Broker and you could create custom mechanism like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41909818/5070879)

Answer (score 135):

SQL Server Express [doesn't include SQL Server Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express#Capabilities), so it's not possible to just create SQL Agent jobs.

What you can do is:
You can create jobs "manually" by creating batch files and SQL script files, and running them via Windows Task Scheduler.
For example, you can backup your database with two files like this:

**backup.bat:**

```
sqlcmd -i backup.sql
```

**backup.sql:**

```
backup database TeamCity to disk = 'c:\backups\MyBackup.bak'
```

Just put both files into the same folder and exeute the batch file via Windows Task Scheduler.

The first file is just a Windows batch file which calls the [sqlcmd utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) and passes a SQL script file.
The SQL script file contains T-SQL. In my example, it's just one line to backup a database, but you can put any T-SQL inside. For example, you could do some `UPDATE` queries instead.

---

If the jobs you want to create are for backups, index maintenance or integrity checks, you could also use the excellent [Maintenance Solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/) by Ola Hallengren.

It consists of a bunch of stored procedures (and SQL Agent jobs for non-Express editions of SQL Server), and in the [FAQ](https://ola.hallengren.com/frequently-asked-questions.html) there’s a section about how  to run the jobs on SQL Server Express:

> ## How do I get started with the SQL Server Maintenance Solution on SQL Server Express?
>
> SQL Server Express has no SQL Server Agent. Therefore, the execution of the stored procedures must be scheduled by using cmd files and Windows Scheduled Tasks. Follow these steps.
>
> SQL Server Express has no SQL Server Agent. Therefore, the execution
> of the stored procedures must be scheduled by using cmd files and
> Windows Scheduled Tasks. Follow these steps.
>
> 1. Download MaintenanceSolution.sql.
> 2. Execute MaintenanceSolution.sql. This script creates the stored procedures that you need.
> 3. Create cmd files to execute the stored procedures; for example:
>    sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d master -Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory =
>    N'C:\Backup', @BackupType = 'FULL'" -b -o C:\Log\DatabaseBackup.txt
> 4. In Windows Scheduled Tasks, create tasks to call the cmd files.
> 5. Schedule the tasks.
> 6. Start the tasks and verify that they are completing successfully.

Comment: Where should I specify login info?

Comment: @HasanGürsoy If you're creating a scheduled task that runs SQLCMD (with or w/out a BAT file), I would recommend you use SQLCMD's "-E" parameter, for windows authentication.  For that to work, define a SQL Server login, for the windows user that is the owner of your windows scheduled task.  If unclear which windows login the task runs under, put  "WHOAMI" (DOS command) in the BAT file & capture the BAT file output, to see who's executing.

Comment: @HasanGürsoy Or, for SQL Server authentication, I would put the password in the windows scheduled task (where permissions govern who can read it), instead of putting it in a file anywhere.  It goes on the BAT file command line.  If it's the first parameter being passed to the BAT file, then within the BAT file you can refer to it as %1, on the SQLCMD line for example.

Answer (score 46):

The functionality of creating SQL Agent Jobs is not available in SQL Server Express Edition. An alternative is to execute a batch file that executes a SQL script using Windows Task Scheduler.

In order to do this first create a batch file named **sqljob.bat**

```
sqlcmd -S servername -U username -P password -i <path of sqljob.sql>
```

Replace the `servername`, `username`, `password` and `path` with yours.

Then create the SQL Script file named **sqljob.sql**

```
USE [databasename]
--T-SQL commands go here
GO
```

Replace the `[databasename]` with your database name. The `USE` and `GO` is necessary when you write the SQL script.

`sqlcmd` is a command-line utility to execute SQL scripts. After creating these two files execute the batch file using Windows Task Scheduler.

**NB:** An almost same answer was posted for this question before. But I felt it was incomplete as it didn't specify about login information using `sqlcmd`.

Comment: Where would I save that sqljob.sql? and how can i put when it will execute?

Comment: @WTFZane, it doesn't matter, as long as the location is available from whoever the batch file is executing. (in the script above, replace `path of sqljob.sql` with whatever location you use). Remember that a `*.sql` file here is nothing more than just a text file.

Answer (score 16):

SQL Server Express editions are limited in some ways - one way is that they don't have the SQL Agent that allows you to schedule jobs.

There are a few third-party extensions that provide that capability - check out e.g.:

- [Express Agent for SQL Server Express: Jobs, Jobs, Jobs and Mail](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/Express-Agent-for-SQL-Server-Express_3A00_-Jobs_2C00_-Jobs_2C00_-Jobs_2C00_-and-Mail) (latest update is from 2005, it isn't maintained anymore).
- [SQL Scheduler](http://www.lazycoding.com/products.aspx)