# Schedule CSV Import in SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: csv, import, sql-server-express, web-scraping, schedule

I am using a data scraper app which scrapes the data from single webpage and generates a CSV file.
I want to bulk import the data in SQL Express 2008 from this csv file at FREQUENT INTERVALS.

Please suggest a solution to schedule data import by first truncating the entire table than importing the fresh data.

In SQL Server I know it can be done via SQL Server Agent but I have no idea how to do it in SQL Server Express.

Or It would be great if you can suggest a single solution to scrap the tabular data (at fixed intervals) from a webpage and import it directly in the DB and produce some log.

Can it be done via some ETL tool?

I am looking for some open source light-weight solution to achieve this but if there is none than please suggest a commercial solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create jobs in SQL Server Express edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition) - check out the responses to this very similar question that was posted very recently. SQL Server Express doesn't have SQL Agent built-in - but there are third-party alternatives.