# How to copy mdf file into a folder with c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm using c# and I have a small SQL Server database that I need to copy into a folder `C:\databases\`, the method name is `CreateCopy`.

But at File.Copy row appear an error: 
`"The Process cannot Access the File, because it is being use by another Process"`

I read that File.Copy can be execute only after shut SqlServer down or Detach that database, create a copy and turn SqlServer on again. But how to do it by code?

This is the method that I was trying to use:

```
public static void CreateCopy()
{
    try
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MDF_CONNECTION_STRING);

        String dbpath = String.Format(@"C:\databases\{0:yyyyMMdd}.mdf", Cash, date);
        File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database.mdf", dbpath);
        String lgpath = String.Format(@"C:\databases\{0:yyyyMMdd}_log.ldf", Cash, date);
        File.Copy(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database_log.ldf", lgpath);    
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error", e);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**INFO**
This is not a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681009/copy-sql-server-mdf-and-ldf-files-while-server-is-in-use) because i don't need to do create a bak file, i need to **archive** this database. I need just to copy these two files (.mdf and .ldf) into a folder. And that answers didn't help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy SQL Server MDF and LDF files while server is in use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681009/copy-sql-server-mdf-and-ldf-files-while-server-is-in-use)

Comment: @Mate is not a duplicate i explained also the reason

Comment: Just to take a bkp is not necessary stop the service. In that question explains how to stop and start  the service... read all answers

Comment: You need to stop SQL Server first then copy the data and then start it again.

Comment: Backup of DB should also be considered as archiving as it will hold the same information as the .mdf and .ldf togeather in a single file? Are you okay to stop SQL Server and copy over the files to your archive location and start   SQL Server back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database files .mdf and .ldf files are used by the SQL Server engine.

If you DETACH database from SQL Server instance, then you can copy or move those files.

But when you DETACH db, it will be unaccessible!

So it is better to run a [backup command in SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/ms-sql-server-backup-script.aspx) then use it.

Comment: Thank you, is better do backup than risk to leave database unacessible! :)

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that you are looking for the code which will help you to [Programmatically Enumerating, Attaching, and Detaching SQL Server Databases](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72465/Programmatically-Enumerating-Attaching-and-Detachi) So that you can copy the MDF file to the location. You can also have a look on [How to Backup and Restore](http://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/how-to-backup-and-restore-sql-express-2005-attachdbfilename-mode) to get the idea of AttachDbFilename mode.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(MDF_CONNECTION_STRING);` it will access the `.mdf` file and give it after the `File.Copy()` execute. because at the time of execution of `File.Copy()` the file is being used by `SqlConnection` that's because you are getting such error

Comment: The problem is that the SQLServer is running, and remove that connection row doesn't help me