# Cannot start SQL Agent in SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-express, sql-server-agent

So my SQL Server Express version does not allow the SQL Agent service to run. I want to automate a query to execute about every 10 seconds. I suppose, given my task, it could be done every minute.

Is there a way to execute an automated SQL query without the SQL Agent? I am seeing all kinds of different ways, but not sure which to use.

How do I schedule a windows task to run the SQ Query?

Thanks in advance for your valued assistance.

Comment: **Express** does not support the SQL Server Agent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create jobs in SQL Server Express edition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition)

Comment: I understand that EXPRESS does not support the Server Agent. I was exloring options beyond using the SQL Server Agent. Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to that duplicate I've mentioned - I had links to two alternatives for SQL Server Agent listed there