# do something in a specific time by sql server and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

do something in a specific time by sql server and asp.net:

I want to send an email to my website customers automatically by SQL Server's job method or email when their registration time is expired.
My sql server version is express edition 2008.

Comment: what do u mean with .. "server management system's job "?? does this mean mail should be done by SSMS

Comment: So Whats the question?

Comment: best way would be to develop a Windows Service that executes every x mins and sends an email. it is not really the responsibility of SQL Server to do this, whilst even though it is possible. I also do not believe the express version allows such jobs but only in full versions of SQL. so again, Windows Service solution is applicable here.

Comment: Correct, the Express version doesn't have access to the Server Agent (which is how you make stored procedures and jobs). Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition) link will help you out