# SQL Server 2008 R2 does not show Database Mail

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my local system. But it does not show Database Mail option under the Management folder. Also once I have tried to start SQL Server Agent from Administrative Tools > Services > Sql Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS). It shows message like some process are not use so SQL Server Agent stop.

Is there any other way to start SQL Server Agent?

I have tried to start Database Mail using XPs option, but it was not work.

Thanks,

Uttam Patel

Comment: ["Database Mail is not available in SQL Server Express."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: And SQL Server **Express** also doesn't support SQL Server Agent - see e.g. [this other SO question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition)

Answer (score 2):

Database Mail is only available in Enterprise Edition, not in Sql Server Express Edition.

Comment: yeh same thing i was struggling.. now got missing the Enterprise Edition