# Application with SQL Server express and scheduling a backup everyday

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, database-backups

I have an application that is used by more than one user, however backups need to be performed twice a day. I don't have SQL server agent and i was wondering if i should create an exe that would run in the background.

I have read other posts about using the scheduler, but i would look it to be away from the end user and simple exe is used. As i am looking to incorporate sending an email once back up is complete.

basically what is the best approach for creating a backup on SQL server and how does other applications allow for this?

**Update**
Would a good idea be to create a windows service that checks the time, if time matches then perform backup, i have never created a windows service. 
What are the positives and negatives ?
will this start on pc boot?
any other suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition

Comment: Task scheduler is the easier way to go.  If you want to write a service there is a lot of documentation on the [Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx) that can help you.  Yes services can be setup to start on logon.  Don't forget your service will always be running.  Make sure your time check loop doesn't consume too much RAM/CPU.  Scheduled tasks will only run when requested.