# How to SSIS package automatically executes a day?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

Does anyone know what to do to SSIS package a daily automatically executed?
I use SQL Server Management Studio Express 2012, VS2015 and SSDT 2015. I know in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Express is no SQL Server Agent job, through which i could solve the problem. I'm new in ssis.
Does anyone know the another way?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a version other than SQL Express?

Comment: Since you have no Integration Service running (that comes only with non-free SQL Server SKU), your only chance is to run Visual Studio (devenv.exe) and run your package from there.

Comment: Unfortunately now I can not.

Comment: Thanks for advices. Is there a SQL function to execute SSIS packages?

Comment: Or Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a sql query that run ssis package and save it in a file then create a batch file that execute this file. And assign this batch file to a windows scheduler task

Look at this [Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition) 
For creating jobs in express edition

And this [Topic](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2135/run-ssis-using-xpcmdshell-in-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/) contains how to run package from query

Hope it helps you

Comment: It helped me. Thank you.

Comment: It is the only way to do it using sql express without writing an application :). If answer solved your issue mark it.