# How to perform loop-like operations in SQL to copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, loops

I have a problem where I need to copy data from one database into another, I am never guaranteed to have the data available in realtime, and sometimes I might need to process 5 days' of data in one go etc. The processing day should operate over a period from 7am one day to 6:59am the next day, for example, between 2017-08-01 07:00 and 2017-08-02 06:59.

I would like to use SQL but without any looping constructs is possible, but I am do not know how to convert the psuedo code below into the required SQL statements, thus any help would be appreciated:

```
declare @lastDate datetime
set @lastDate = (select max(dc) from dmt)

do
    if gettime() => 07:00 then
        if @lastDate < getdate() then
            insert id, dc into dmt where dc between @lastdate and @lastdate + 1 day from othertable
        end if
    end if

    set @lastDate = (select max(dc) from dmt)
while @lastDate < getdate()
```

I am using SQL Express 2012. The id is an int and dc is a datetime. dmt is the table where I want to store the copied information and othertable is where I want to copy from.

Thanks.

Comment: Look into 'Cursor' examples

Comment: Is the source and destination different for each day? Is there a reason you can't just do it all at once as opposed to looping for each day?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean Xedni, new records are added to the other table everyday for all different times of the day, and each day I need to summarise them and copy them into the dmt table because they are dropped from other table every week. Only the summarised data will be retained and I need to ensure that the dmt contains a summarised record for each day.

Answer (score 0):

this is how the code would look like, by using SQL, and i think you need a sql job task to be scheduled in the time of the day you need, please check this about creating jobs with sql server Express Edition

[How to create jobs in SQL Server Express edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition)

```
    declare @lastDate datetime
set @lastDate = (select max(dc) from dmt)


INSERT INTO DMT(ID,DC)

    SELECT ID,DC 
    FROM OTHER_TABLE
    WHERE DC BETWEEN @LASTDATE AND DATEADD(DAY,1,@lastDate)
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,TIME_FIELD) >=7
```

Comment: I don't think that will work Ronaldo, there needs to be some element of iteration to cover all the days that might be present in the other table... the other table is not accesible to me everyday, it is given as table dumps.

Comment: the select statement will return a dataset with all the rows you need, i think it is not necessary to build a loop

Comment: And how will it work when the other table contains let's say 10 days worth of information? Without a loop or similar the new table will only contain the last date plus the next day.

Comment: in that case you need a task to execute the insert into the new table, you can schedule the task maybe every hour of the day, you could use a SQL Server Job to accomplish this

Comment: Yes. I agree that method could work, but I was hoping to do everything in bulk using one query that would run once every time the data dump happened. I'm thinking ahead to running this query on the archived data where there will be thousands of days to summarise.

Comment: if you have access to modify the source database, maybe you can create a trigger that inserts the data into your new table every time a row is inserted into the source table

Comment: No. I don't have access and many rows in the source are summarised before adding to the destination... one record in the destination comes from summarising hundreds of records from the source.