# Sql server management - no user agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to create a job and schedule for it to run in accordance to.

I read in Microsoft documentation that I need a sql server agent for that and it should be sitting under object explorer. I cannot find it, however.

I am using sql server 2016. Does anyone how to make it show up so that I can make it run a job?

[image: No sql server agent]

[image: Sql Version used]

Comment: Are you using MS Sql Server Express edition?

Comment: Are you using SQL Azure?

Comment: I am not sure. Nowhere says that it is an express edition. How can I confirm? I have posted a picture with an "about" regarding the version. That is a local database.

Comment: `Select @@version` - what does this return?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 6.3 <X64> (Build 16299: )

Comment: Bingo, so you have the `Express Edition` which doesn't include `Sql Server Agent`. Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

The version is Express Edition. That's why.