# Running background stored procedure using sp_procoption and waitfor time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, background, sql-server-express, master-db

I have created a stored procedure in my SQL Server Express that I am calling my Web API in and it is running fine. I want it to play in the background like a job / schedule using `waitfor` time in SQL Server to auto start it at startup of master.

Stored procedure:

```
USE [master]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyBackgroundTask]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @timeToRun NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @timeToRun = 'time'

    WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR time @timeToRun
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE [master].[dbo].[CALLWEBSERVICE];
        END
    END
END
```

To start with the master startup I have used `sp_procoption`:

```
sp_procoption    @ProcName = 'MyBackgroundTask',
                @OptionName = 'startup',
                @OptionValue = 'on'
GO
```

I have also used this query to get the list of routine task running in background:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME
FROM MASTER.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(ROUTINE_NAME),'ExecIsStartup') = 1
```

I have also got it running in background but **how** can I **check** if it is really working in background how can I check the **result** I got in background running stored procedure?

I tried SQL Server Express Profiler but not helpful it is not showing background procedures in it.

Comment: Why not create a sql job that simply runs your procedure. Then put that job on a schedule. What you have created here is an endless loop.

Comment: @SeanLange yes you are right but I have SQL Express installed and don't have SQL Agent in it as it is available in Enterprise addition so can't create job in Express that's why I have put it running endless that is how I have scheduled it by my own call / method.

Comment: Or download SQL Server Developer Edition if you are not planning on using your code to generate revenue or for commercial purposes. That has the job agent.

Comment: Doing this in an endless loop is a clear sign that something is not right. You could always create an application that calls your procedure and set it up to run as a windows task. That is still rather kludgey but way better than an endless loop.

Comment: I agree with @SeanLange, Good day to you sir.

Comment: @dfundako as of now I can only use sql express.

Comment: sp_whoisactive/sp_who2 would show the open spid running your endless process.

Comment: @MahavirsinhPadhiyar This question is a possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201061/how-to-create-jobs-in-sql-server-express-edition), please see the post I added, it gives 3rd party software extensions for use with Express to do what SQL Agent does, it also shows how to create a batch file to run your stored procedure and then set that up as a windows service, as Sean suggested.