# SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action

Tags: sql, sql-server-agent

This is for very first time that I am trying to use SQL server Agent. 
I get this error :

```
Msg 22022, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action.
```

I went to services to check if it was running. I tried to start it and got this immediately . The services then stopped ofcourse.:
[image: error]

Then I tried with SQL server configuration manager:

On trying to start the service there,
[image]

When I try to change the log on account via SQL server configuration manager:

[image]

How do I get this service started ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server Express editions does not include the SQL Server Agent component. If you want that you need to use any of the versions that includes it (Enterprise, Business Intelligence, Standard or Web).

Reference: [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993.aspx) (the same limits applies to earlier editions too).

Comment: Thank you. So, are all of these paid versions ?

Comment: @Simran I believe so, yes. If you just need the functionality of the Agent then there are some possible solutions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3789024/1175077

Answer (score 11):

It can happen as well that you have SQL Service Agent installed on your server with the database, but as the message says it is not running.

Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services and check if service SQL Service Agent is running.